# Angular no http request when subscribed via pipe()

Tags: angular, http, angular2-observables

I am quite new to angular and tried to check if a username already exists by sending a http request to my server, but my server isn't getting any requests.

in my Service:

```
checkUsername(name: string): Observable<boolean> {
return this.http.get(
  `${this.api}/checkusername/${name}`
).pipe(
  catchError(this.errorHandler)
);
}
```

in my Validator:

```
export class UsernameExistsVallidatorService implements AsyncValidator{
constructor(private vs: VallidatorsService) { }

  validate(control: FormControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return this.vs.checkUsername(control.value).pipe(
      map(exists => (exists === false) ? null : {
          isbnExists: { valid: false }
      }),
      catchError(() => of(null))
    );
  }
}
```

In my server:

```
app.get("/api/checkusername/:name", (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  console.log(req.params.name);
  res.json({exists: false});
});
```

As you can see the server prints every name and for now it answers with {exists: false}.

If I put

```
this.vs.checkUsername(control.value).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

inside my validate function, the server receives everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For the getting request from serve you always needs `subscribe`

`http.post (and get, put, delete, etc)` returns a cold `Observable`, i.e. an `Observable` for which:

> its underlying producer is created and activated during subscription

This means the function represented by the Observable is activated only with the `subscribe()` method.

or

```
 post() : Promise<any> {
     return this.http.post(
       '/api, 
        {}
     ).toPromise();
```

or

```
post() {
    var observable = this.http.post('/api', {})
        .map(response => response.json()) // in case you care about returned json       
        .publishReplay(); // would be .publish().replay() 
    observable.connect();
    return observable;
}
```